# Shall we ban unregistered users?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, new-users, users

Some sites have [banned unregistered users](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/317/5) from posting on their site. Related discussions to that thread include [this one](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/368/5) and [this one](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/270/5).

Shall we do the same here? My opinion is that allowing users to ask questions without making an account, is something that sites probably do when they want a larger volume of questions and care less about quality. The question is whether or not this community wants that, or has other opinions that they'd like to share about this question.

Comment: I'm pretty neutral on this issue. I can't think of a time this actually happened and was a problem

Comment: I noticed it being a problem in a recent case but have no time right now.

Comment: I'd say this is only an issue if it happens somewhat regularly, and the quality is clearly below what new registered users post.